# How can I tell what my php script is doing before it finishes loading?

Tags: php

I have a simple php program that analyzes a text ([here's the source on github](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/bulk-etym/blob/master/etym.php), and [here's a somewhat-working demo](http://jonreeve.com/dev/etym/etym.php)), but it's excruciatingly slow. Since I'm a beginning programmer, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. In python or something, I'd print out debugging messages every step of the way while the program was running, but with php, I don't seem to get any messages until the entire script has run its course. How can I output useful debugging information before the script has finished running, so I can tell which functions are taking the longest time?

Comment: Profile your code with xdebug to generate a grind file. Load that up in a profiler and you'll discover which function(s) are taking the most time to complete and what you need to focus on.

Comment: Xdebug isn't allowed on my hosting provider, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ob_flush()` and `flush()` to send data as the code is running:

```
echo "status message 1";
ob_flush();flush();
```

Comment: Cool. I made this in a function: `function debug_print($message) { echo $message; ob_flush(); flush();`

Answer (score 0):

you can always [flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) all output buffer